# Illuminate HTML on Laravel 5 broke my html

Tags: php, html, laravel

I actually have a problem and I can't find the issue. I just call an easy form by :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo.bar') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

And the problem is it just prints on my html page the form, and in source code the HTML is broken, it gives me garbage like this:

```
&lt;form method=&quot;POST&quot; action=&quot;http://localhost/laravel/public/users&quot; accept-charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;&lt;input name=&quot;_token&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;xFAP4YixoTzGHKcECn7RP418CWdbJ97A8llkUMxt&quot;&gt;

        &lt;/form&gt;
```

Comment: you have to use {!! Form::open()!!} and {!! Form::close() !!} in l5, because l5 will escape data by default

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @terrylow thanks!! yea ofc i just forgot this rule on l5...